# Question regarding apple charges

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store, ipod-touch

Will apple charge 30% of the app revenue or 30% of the content we sell through our own app?

For example if we sell a book from our App, will apple charge 30% of that book we sold?

or

Apple charges 30% of the app price? (example if the app costs 10USD, apple takes 3USD)?

Please clear my doubt. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Apple charges 30% of every revenues generated through iTunes Connect.

So they get 30% of the price of you app and 30% of the price of everything you sell using inApp purchase and 30% of every ad revenues that you would generate throught iAd.

30% of everything they can ! That's the rule :-D

Answer (score 1):

Can I see any link in apple that states this?..because I just seen the store listing process...They didnt mention anything that take 30% revenue of anything sold through app... here it goes... iPhone Application Store Listing Process:

After our developers have developed, tested and debugged your iPhone application we submit the app to Apple's iPhone Application Store. The Application can be available for free distribution or sold. If you want to sell the application the base price is $0.99 and the maximum is $999.99, most of the commercial iPhone apps are available for about $10 on the iPhone store. The price is decided solely by you. Apple charges 30% of the sales revenue as retailing fees while you retain rest 70% of the sales revenue generated. There are no fees charged for free apps. The maximum application file size permitted is 2GB.